# Only closed homoclinic orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

Given a fixed vector field $\dot{\mathbb{x}}(t)$ and a fixed point $\mathbb{x}^{*}$. Is it necessary that the orbit that satisfies $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \mathbb{\phi} (t) = \mathbb{x}^{*} $ (where $\phi (t)$ is the trajectory) be closed? I mean, Should an homoclinic be a closed orbit in the phase space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically a homoclinc orbit doesn't include the limit $x^*$ and therefore is not closed (nor open for phase spaces of dimension $>1$).

However, the set $H=\phi(\mathbb{R}) \cup \{x^*\}$ is closed (sketch of proof):

Assume that there exists $y \neq x^*, \not \in H$ that is a limit point of $H$ and pick $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2} d(y, x^*)$. Since $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \phi(t) = x^*$, there exists $R> 0$ such that for all $|t|\geq R$ we have that $d(\phi(t), x^*)\leq \epsilon$. Therefore $y$ is not a limit point of $\phi \left( (-\infty, -R] \cup [R, \infty) \right)$. Since $\phi(t)$ is continuous (as the solution of a differential equation) and $[-R, R]$ is compact, we have that $\phi([-R,R])$ is compact and therefore contains all of its limit points. Thus we have that $y$ is not a limit point of $\phi([-R, R])$.

This leaves nowhere for a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to exist such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(t_n) = y$. In other words, $H \subseteq \phi([-R, R]) \cup \overline{B_\epsilon (x^*)}$.

Comment: is it possible a limit cycle to contain homoclinic orbits finishing assimptotically in it?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean--something like having the unit circle as an attracting periodic orbit while having a homoclinic point at the origin?

Comment: It’s like having the unit circle in polar coordinates, and starting in a point $r_{0}$ the orbits with $\lim_{\phi \to \pm \infty}$  tends to $r = 1$. Can I say that $ r=1$ is a limite cycle?

Comment: Let's see if I'm following correctly: Take a fixed point at $(r_0, \theta_0) = (1,0)$ which has a homoclinic orbit of the unit circle $r=1$. Let another trajectory start inside the unit circle and spiral outwards. Note that each time the trajectory passes by $(1,0)$, it will slow down but still pass through the neighborhood in finite time. The limit set for this trajectory will be the entire unit circle $r=1$, but it would *not* be called a limit cycle as we have a homoclinic orbit there, not a cycle (no periodicity). This is moving towards the realm of a new question =)